# Need to produce url dynamically in spring boot for swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, tigergraph

Have this small code snippet

```
public ApiInfo getApiInformation(){
    return new ApiInfo("EPGRAPH-API",
        "This is EPGRAPH-API created to load Edges and Vertex to TigerGraph",
        "1.0",
        "",
         new Contact("EEPGraph Team", "http://localhost:8080/avc/xyz”, ""),
        "",
        "",
        Collections.emptyList()
    );
}
```

At the line  `new Contact("EEPGraph Team", "http://localhost:8080/avc/xyz”, "")`, I need to replace
http://localhost:8080/avc/xyz dynamically so that every time when application run, it takes url dynamically in stead of hardcoding the value.

Comment: why don't you pass it as method param? getApiInformation(String URL)

Comment: What part f the url do you need to be dynamic? The domain? The path? The port? And how do you want to retrieve the dynamic parts of the url?